# Are all verbs imperative?

Tags: verbs, imperatives

It seems that all basic verbs can be considered imperative verbs. Can someone point me to a counter-example?

Comment: How about the first verb in your text? I can't easily see how to construct an idiomatically viable imperative sentence with ***to seem*** as the only verb.

Comment: Just because a form is spelled the same way doesn't mean it's grammatically the same: "Shut up!" is not: "I told him to shut up."  The first is imperative and the second is the bare verb form.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "a basic verb"? Do you mean the infinitive form? 2. You seem to be confusing form and function: (a) "Can you play the piano?" (b) "Play the piano." in (a) "play" is an infinitive; (b) is an imperative.

Comment: I'm sure "seem" could be used as an imperative. It's common to use "look" in the sense of appear/seem as an imperative, both in standard phrases like "look lively!" and more individual constructions. It's not uncommon to tell someone to appear to be some thing. (Although I'm not sure if this is the exact question, or if it's a question about whether the imperative is always the same as the basic form of the verb.)

Comment: Thank you @Lambie and Greybeard, that clarified my understanding.